# TurboPascal default Calling Convention

Tags: pascal, calling-convention

What is the default Calling Convention in TurboPascal? Variables should put in which registers  or put into the stack LTR or RTL?

Comment: Look through a bunch of old TP sources like SWAG?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the Turbo Pascal I knew long ago, it's the Pascal convention: parameters pushed on the stack left to right and the called function cleans up.

Comment: And return value of a function in `ax` or `eax` if it's an x86 processor